# Android studio - internally search for dependencies in jcenter or maven central

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, android-studio, maven-central, jcenter

Is there anyway in the android studio IDE to search for a dependency instead of going on [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) site  or maven central ? In Eclipse there is a way to search for things from the help menu -->install new software

Update: there is also https://github.com/cesarferreira/alfi which can be used as a library finder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Project Structure > Dependencies > + button > Library dependency, there's a search function.

Comment: Its funny i checked that yesterday but must have missed it. Excellent response.